# Spring Data JPA - Paged Repository with Specification based on multiple entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA in a project that relies on multiple databases.

In one database (call it ContactDB) we have a `Contact` that is tied to a `User` in the other database (call it UserDB) via a `userId` on the `Contact`.

In the UserDB, a `User` can have multiple `Store` entities. See below the entity classes defined for each DB.

`Contact` Entity:

```
package com.mycompany.cdb.entity;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACT", schema = "cSchema")
public class Contact {
    private Long contactId;
    private Long userId;
    private String firstNm;
    private String lastNm;

    //other fields, getters with jpa column definition annotations, setters, etc.
}
```

`User` Entity:

```
package com.mycompany.udb.entity;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER", schema = "uSchema")
public class User {
    private Long userId;
    private Collection<Store> stores;

    //other fields, getters with jpa column difinition annotations, setters, etc.
}
```

Each database has its own configuration class that configures a `TransactionManager`, `EntityManagerFactory`, etc.

The ContactDB config class has an `EntityManagerFactory` that looks for entities in the `com.mycompany.cdb.entity` package, while the UserDB's `EntityManagerFactory` looks for entities in the `com.mycompany.udb.entity` package.

This is all set up correctly and works with the current application.

Now, I am trying to add a `PagingAndSortingRepository` for the `Contact` entity that uses a `Specification` for filtering.

```
@Repository
public interface PagingAndSortingContactRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Contact, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {

}
```

Here is an example `Specification` I have implemented that will filter by `firstNm` and `lastNm`.

```
public class PagingAndSortingContactSpecification {

    public static Specification<Contact> findByFirstNameAndLastName(final String firstNm, final String lastNm) {
        return new Specification<Contact>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Contact> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                final Predicate firstNmPredicate = null;
                final Predicate lastNmPredicate = null;
                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(firstNm)) {
                    firstNmPredicate = cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(Contact_.firstNm), firstNm));
                }
                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(lastNm)) {
                    lastNmPredicate = cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(Contact_.lastNm), lastNm));
                }
                return cb.and(firstNmPredicate, lastNmPredicate);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

And I call that `Specification` using the `PagingAndSortingContactRepository` in a service class like so.

```
@Inject
private PagingAndSortingContactRepository pagingAndSortingContactRepository;

public Page<Contact> getContactsByFirstNmLastNm(String firstNm, String lastNm, Pageable pageable) {    
    return pagingAndSortingContactRepository
        .findAll(PagingAndSortingContactSpecification.findByFirstNameAndLastName(firstNm, lastNm),pageable);
}
```

Now, I need to create a `Specification` that will filter out `Contact` entities based on what `Store` entities that their corresponding `User` entity is tied to.

I believe this may be able to be accomplished if the `User` could be mapped in the `Contact` entity, but since they are in different databases, that is not possible.

So, is it possible to create a `Specification` that will take in a list of store ids, to filter out `Contact` entities that have a `User` that is tied to any `Store` entities corresponding to the list passed in?

Something like this: (This isn't valid syntax. Just trying to help demonstrate what I would like to accomplish.)

```
public static Specification<Contact, User> findByStores(final Collection<Long> storeIds) {
    return new Specification<Contact, User>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Contact, User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            return cb.in(root.get(User_.stores), storeIds);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get when you execute query with findByStore specification? Could you show mappings between you entities?

Comment: @borysfan That's not actual code I have implemented. I don't believe `Specification<T, T>` is actually a valid syntax. I'm merely searching for a way to do something similar.